# Are there specifications for SAS export files when the data dictionary is split into input/format/label files?

Tags: sas

I'm trying to import data from SAS exports posted publicly. I am not using SAS to import these files, but importing them via custom script into another format. There are no specifications that I could find, but it seems pretty self-explanatory if you're used to databases.

And then I found a dictionary file that specifies the last three columns as having lengths of 11.5, 12.5, and 9.5 characters. This makes zero sense to me.

```
@2682  PATWT            11.5      /* Patient visit weight used for national, regional, and divisional estimates                                                                                                                                                   */
@2693  PATWTST          12.5      /* Patient visit weight used for state estimates                                                                                                                                                                                */
@2705  PHYSWT           9.5       /* Weight used for physician-level estimates based on responding in-scope physicians seeing */
```

An explanation of this, or being pointed to official SAS specifications for this format would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Can you post the full script, at least we can see the function?

Comment: Full script at this directory ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/dataset_documentation/namcs/sas the files nam15for.txt/nam15inp.txt/nam15lab.txt are the data dictionaries for the flat file namcs15 found in another directory ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Datasets/NAMCS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

11.5 is an IN-format specification.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering about that. A few reasons I didn't think that. 1) the data already has decimal points 2) while PATWTST indeed has five figures after the decimal point, PATWT only has four figures 3) other datasets released on this website, like at ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Dataset_Documentation/NHAMCS/sas/ed16inp.txt the PATWT has no decimal designation, but the field data has decimals

Comment: Also - can you please direct me to where you got that specification from? Thanks.

Comment: It is from the online documentation for the w.d format.